# get Embeddings by reloading tensorflow model

Tags: python, tensorflow

I saved a tensorflow model, .pb file, trained using transfer learning [taking this](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py#L761) as reference with following code added at the end:

`tf.train.write_graph(graph_name, saving_dir_path, output.pb, as_text=False)`

and it successfully saved. But now after training I want to get Embedding's output. Following is the last layer defined to train in the graph under layer name `final_training_ops`:

```
with tf.name_scope('Wx_plus_b'):
      logits = tf.add(tf.matmul(bottleneck_input, layer_weights), layer_biases, name='logits')
```

After reloading saved model I am using `tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('Wx_plus_b/logits')` to access layer so as to pass image to get embeddings but getting error as **invalid operation name**.

Answer (score 0):

I gave more time to it and found correct syntax is of the form `<op_name>:<output_index>` -

`tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('Wx_plus_b/logits:0')`